# How to insert data from one form in different database table in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel. I want to register the account so I have one form that has the details about the username, email, password, company name, and other company details. I got 2 tables in my database. Table 1 is the **user** table which is used to store the user details to log in like userID, email, password, and companyID (from table 2). Table 2 is the **company** table that stores company details. Table 2 has companyID, companyName, and so on. I want to ask how can I use one form to save my data in two different tables.

Here is the code from RegisterController

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First You Need To Insert In Company Table Then User Table Like This .

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
   $company=Company::create([
       'companyName'=>$data['companyName']
   ]);

    User::create([
        'username' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'companyID'=>$company->id
    ]);
 }
```

Comment: @Vivel vaghela, thank you for your reply. I will try with your answer

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a very elegant solution for this. First you have to set the relations between both models. As it happens, your example can now cover both directions. That's why I now assume: a user can have many companies and a company only one user.

This means that in the user model you set the relation

```php
protected function companies() {
    return $this->hasMany(Company::class);
}
```

And in the Company Model you set this method:

```php
protected function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Then in your controller, service etc. you can call the following:

```php
$user = User::create([
        'username' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

$company = [
    'companyName' => 'fooBar',
];

$user->companies()->save($company);
```

Link to the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Comment: thank you for your reply, after I follow your code, I get this error Call to undefined method App\User::companies()

Comment: @dipgirl this error means that the componies() method is missing in the user model

Comment: after I change to $user->User::companies()->save($company);
it work then come out this error : Class name must be a valid object or a string

Comment: @dipgirl this error means that you dont have Company as model in your application. or he didnt find it. you have these file under `app/models/Company.php? and the class name is Company.

Comment: ok I check again